# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined in backend.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got this Error in my Angular 8 project while loading http://localhost:4200

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
        at new t (backend.js:31)
        at Object.<anonymous> (backend.js:31)
        at Object.<anonymous> (backend.js:31)
        at r (backend.js:1)
        at Object.<anonymous> (backend.js:31)
        at r (backend.js:1)
        at Object.<anonymous> (backend.js:31)
        at r (backend.js:1)
        at Object.<anonymous> (backend.js:31)
        at r (backend.js:1)

this.clearImmediate=t.clearImmediate.bind(t);else{this.nextHandle=1,this.tasksByHandle={},this.currentlyRunningATask=!1,this.canUseProcessNextTick()
```

Comment: As the error states, `t.clearImmediate` is undefined. Check why that is by placing a breakpoint there.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46707216/react-cannot-read-property-bind-of-undefined/46707299

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure 
`t.clearImmediate`is defined before calling `.bind()`method on it.

Comment: Thanks for response Ismail, Here I am not able to identify when that backend.js get called. even though if I put debug point, it bypasses.

Answer (score 0):

Either your own code, or one of your project's dependencies, must be using `clearImmediate`, which is a MSIE-only thing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/clearImmediate